# Format multiple SQL columns or do it in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, echo

I have a database with many columns all with year names. Inside of them on every row are numbers with a type of integer. I want them to all have thousand seperators (A dollar sign would be nice but I can add that in easy with php).
-What I have now is the following:

```
 SELECT *, format(`2015`, 0) AS `15`, FROM `FullList`
```

and that gives me the seperators like 1,000,000. The problem is I would have to do that for every column that seems wrong.

in my php I use this as simply

```
<div class=\"example\">$".$row[`15`]."</div>
```

Giving me $1,000,000

I'm hoping to find a good way of doing this in SQL or maybe even PHP so that I don't need to use format on every column.

Comment: See normalisation. A database table is not a spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

Databases should not contain formatting because you are storing information in a standard form which can be read by any application regardless of language. I suppose the column is currently of data-type `float(11,2)` or something similar, which is correct and recommended.

Though it may seem tedious to add a dollar sign in front of every value, displaying a value should be the job of the templating language (in this case PHP) and not the database.

You might want to use PHP's `money_format()` instead:

> http://php.net/money_format

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about money_format. It makes life a lot easier. I'm used to using custom formats in spreadsheets.